# Formula for Schinzel circle with minimum radius

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices

[Schinzel's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchinzelsTheorem.html) states that there are a set of circles with a given number of integer points on the circumference of the circle. The theorem includes the equation for an instance of circle given $n$.

However, the formula does not always give the circle with minimum radius. I am looking for a formula, or at least a procedure to generate the circle with minimum radius given $n$. A brute force search gives first values of the series.

\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{center} & \text{square of radius} & \text{number of points on c} \\
 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) & \frac{1}{2} & 4 \\
 \left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{6}\right) & \frac{625}{18} & 5 \\
 \left(\frac{1}{2},0\right) & \frac{25}{4} & 6 \\
 \left(\frac{9}{22},\frac{5}{22}\right) & \frac{138125}{242} & 7 \\
 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) & \frac{5}{2} & 8 \\
 \left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{6}\right) & \frac{4225}{18} & 9 \\
 \left(\frac{1}{2},0\right) & \frac{625}{4} & 10 \\
\end{array}

There is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422341/finding-circles-on-lattice-points-with-arbitrary-origin/2424545) on math exchange site but the answer is still brute force searching. I am wondering if there is formulas or existing research and paper on the problem.

Comment: You should include a link to the m.se question, and you should put a link to this question there if you haven't already done so.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, that question was deleted several weeks ago

Comment: So, it's not https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422341/finding-circles-on-lattice-points-with-arbitrary-origin/2424545 ? Anyway, some of us can see deleted questions, I still think you should put links.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I got it. I have edited the question.